# Open link in Google Maps with "Full Mode" enabled

Tags: google-maps, url, hyperlink, google-street-view

I discovered that the Google Maps defaults to **Lite Mode**, so this Street View Link do not work:

http://www.google.com/maps?spn=0.008443,0.022767&ctz=-60&t=h&z=16&layer=c&cbll=46.092909769,11.1152051545&cbp=12,44.85,,0,18.41

Can I add a URL parameter to this link to force Full Mode Google Maps, without manually setting it by user?

Comment: About the `street view url`, please read the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=pl&csw=1#url_parameters) may help you.

Comment: Unlucky, in that page there are no useful hints. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add the parameter `force=tt`

So your link would be:

```
http://www.google.com/maps?spn=0.008443,0.022767&ctz=-60&t=h&z=16&layer=c&cbll=46.092909769,11.1152051545&cbp=12,44.85,,0,18.41&force=tt
```